# uninitialized extern NSString usage

Tags: objective-c, c, nsstring, extern

In the following class:

[MGTileMenu](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGTileMenu)

various extern NSString's are defined in the following way for use as notifications:

.h

```
extern NSString *MGTileMenuWillDisplayNotification; // menu will be shown
```

.m

```
NSString *MGTileMenuWillDisplayNotification;
```

It gets used as follows:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:MGTileMenuWillDisplayNotification 
                                                    object:self 
                                                  userInfo:nil];
```

My question is this: The extern NSString MGTileMenuWillDisplayNotification never gets initialized to any value - but this code works. I would have expected the implementation in the .m file to be:

```
NSString *MGTileMenuWillDisplayNotification = @"MGTileMenuWillDisplayNotification";
```

Why is this not necessary and what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

This means that the actual variable is defined in other parts of the program. Probably within some framework or library. You do not even have to have the related source.

The `extern` keyword tells the linker to look up the symbol table for a symbol named `MGTileMenuWillDisplayNotification` . (I think that would be a static variable, but not sure whether it coud be something else.)

`NSString*` tells the compiler to tread the memory where your pointer points to as `NSString` object. As usual. It is just that it is declared somewhere else and most probalby properly initialized somewhere else. It is in your scope of responsibility to ensure that it really is an `NSString` object which the documentation of the framework/library should tell you.

Comment: But there *is* a static variable `NSString *MGTileMenuWillDisplayNotification;` in MGTileMenuController.m, and the value is `nil`.

Comment: Well, that's the one. It is initialized with nil.

Comment: but the var isn't initialized elsewhere, so it's (implicitly) nil - how can posting a nil notification work then?

Comment: so after checking this with a few breakpoints (which I should have done to begin with..) sending notifs with nil initialised strings doesn't work, so it's just a bug in that class's code.

Comment: I am glad you found it in the end.